# (ionChange) not emitting data in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

`.html`:

```
<ion-select *ngIf="filter_type (ionChange)="choose_type('travels',travels.id,$event)">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let travels of filter_type">
    {{travels.name}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

`.ts`:

```
choose_type(type: string, value: any, event: any) {
  let index;
  if (event.checked === true) {
    this.user_filter[type].push(value);
  } else {   
    index = this.user_filter[type].indexOf(value);
    this.user_filter[type].splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

I am trying to pass `travels.id`, but getting an error as
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

Here I will attach the filter_type array:

```
0: {id: "21", name: "AMC"}
1: {id: "151", name: "VBC"}
2: {id: "329", name: "GFS."}
3: {id: "258", name: "Gu"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use ionSelect on ion-option.

travels is undefined in ion-select because your *ngFor is not applied at this level.

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let travels of filter_type" (ionSelect)=yourFunction >{{travels.name}}</ion-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your comments . Let me post the right answer. The issue was arise since i forget to put value in the option area.

```
  <ion-select  id="filter3" *ngIf="filter_type.travels" (ionChange)="choose_type('travels',$event)" multiple="true">
                        <ion-option id="filter3"  *ngFor="let travels of filter_type.travels " [value]="travels.id">{{travels.name}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
```